Calculate mean value from serie of arrays
I'm looking for a way to calculate the mean value from a series of arrays. The window should contain 3 values ​​and slide to the third last place in the array, then it saves the last 2 values ​​and if the new array arrives within a certain time (e.g. 2 seconds), the last two values ​​are added to the new array and the data is recalculated. If it takes longer than the time, the array starts again and the last two values ​​are discarded. The data is then plotted live (plotting already works, I'm just not getting any further with the calculation). Here is my attempt so far, unfortunately my window freezes.

# -*- coding: latin-1 -*-

import numpy as np
import time

def smooth_data(data, previous_remainder=None):

    """
    Glättet eine Sequenz von Datenpunkten, indem für jedes Fenster von drei aufeinanderfolgenden Datenpunkten der Mittelwert berechnet wird.

    Parameter:
    - data: Eine Sequenz von Datenpunkten, die geglättet werden sollen.
    - previous_remainder: Die letzten beiden Datenpunkte des vorherigen Arrays, die in das aktuelle Array integriert werden sollen.
        Rückgabewerte:
    - smoothed_data: Eine Liste mit den geglätteten Daten.
    - remainder: Die letzten beiden Datenpunkte des verarbeiteten Arrays, die für den nächsten Durchlauf verwendet werden sollen.
    """
    
    if previous_remainder is not None:
        data = np.concatenate((previous_remainder, data))
    
    smoothed_data = []
    remainder = data[-2:]
    
    for i in range(len(data) - 2):
        window = data[i:i+3]
        mean_value = np.mean(window)
        smoothed_data.append(mean_value)
    
    return smoothed_data, remainder



def continuous_data_processing(data, time_window=3.0):
    previous_remainder = None
    last_data = None
    Sensordaten_last = None

    while True:
        Sensordaten_aktuell = data
        
        current_time = time.time()
        if Sensordaten_aktuell is not None and Sensordaten_last is not None and not np.array_equal(Sensordaten_last, Sensordaten_aktuell):
            if last_data is not None and current_time - last_data > time_window:
                previous_remainder = None
        
            filtered_data, remainder = smooth_data(Sensordaten_aktuell, previous_remainder)
            yield filtered_data  # Verwenden Sie yield, um die geglätteten Daten zurückzugeben
        
            last_data = current_time
            previous_remainder = remainder
            Sensordaten_last = Sensordaten_aktuell
       

Edit: This is a simple code example for the job, without the function to proof how long is the time passed beetween 2 aarrays, an this works in an seperate skript. Now i need to include the function for proofing the time from one arraw to a new array, if the time is over 3 seconds, the prog should clean the last 2 saved numbers from the old array an began a new nuber series began with the new array.
Main Modul:
import numpy as np
from filter_modul import smooth_data
import time

def generate_random_data(size):
    return np.random.rand(size)

def main():
    previous_remainder = None  # Initialisierung des previous_remainder
    while True:
        # Erzeugung von Dummy-Daten
        dummy_data = generate_random_data(100)
        raw_data_count = len(dummy_data)  # Anzahl der Rohdaten
        print("Rohdaten:", dummy_data)

        # Glättung der Dummy-Daten mit dem Modul
        smoothed_data, remainder = smooth_data(dummy_data, previous_remainder)

        print("Rohdaten  | Geglättete Daten")
        for raw, smoothed in zip(dummy_data, smoothed_data):
            print(f"{raw:.4f} | {smoothed:.4f}")

        # Separate Schleife, um übrig gebliebene Rohdaten zu drucken
        if len(smoothed_data) < len(dummy_data):
            for raw in dummy_data[len(smoothed_data):]:
                print(f"{raw:.4f} | ")

        print("Anzahl der Rohdatenausgaben:", raw_data_count)

        # Ausgabe des remainder
        print(f"Rest: {remainder[0]:.4f}, {remainder[1]:.4f}")

        time.sleep(4)  # Eine Sekunde warten, bevor neue Daten erzeugt werden
        previous_remainder = remainder  # Aktualisierung des previous_remainder

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

Modul
import numpy as np


def smooth_data(data, previous_remainder=None):

    if previous_remainder is not None:
        data = np.concatenate((previous_remainder, data))

    smoothed_data = []
    remainder = data[-2:]

    for i in range(len(data) - 2):
        window = data[i:i + 3]
        mean_value = np.mean(window)
        smoothed_data.append(mean_value)

    return smoothed_data, remainder


Your question lacks precision. First of all, it is not a [mre]. So we can't try to reproduce the problem, and we don't get what the problem is. Secondly, mean, or median? Those are two different things. Tho, thirdly, I suspect from the wording that this question is more an architecture problem (what ever you do to ensure the timing constraint I didn't exactly understood; what ever "freezes") rather than a computing problem. Confusing meadian and mean may end up in false result, but not freezing.

So, in short, reduce everything down to what is the actual problem, and provide a [mre]

Hello, i will work on the question. First: I need the mean value.

@chrslg I have make an update, hope this is now okay?

Try this in continuous_data_processing
Sensordaten_aktuell = yield

What this does is it prevents blocking and allows smooth handling of incoming data.
Also, try this in the remainder reset part of the same function. I'm not sure that this will fix the issue though
if last_data_time is not None and (current_time - last_data_time) > time_window:
            previous_remainder = None

